# Add popUp Menu button inside a button

Tags: android, popup

I just want to add a popup menu inside a button, which I created using  in XML.[image: Desired Figure]

I did enough research, but couldn't find any solution. Thank You for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.view.MenuItem;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.PopupMenu;  
import android.widget.Toast;  
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
Button button1;  

         @Override  
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

          button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
          button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

           @Override  
           public void onClick(View v) {  
            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu  
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button1);  
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file  
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());  

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener  
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
             public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
              return true;  
             }  
            });  

            popup.show();//showing popup menu  
           }  
          });//closing the setOnClickListener method  
         }  
    }
```